# When I deploy to clojars, should org.clojure/clojure be added or be removed to :dependencies?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojars

When I deploy to clojars, should org.clojure/clojure be added or be removed in :dependencies in project.clj?

- In following tutorial, org.clojure/clojure is added in :dependencies in  project.clj.
  https://github.com/clojars/clojars-web/wiki/Tutorial
- project.clj in some famous library such as clj-http does not include
  org.clojure/clojure as dependencies.
  https://clojars.org/clj-http
- project.clj in other famous library such as ring/ring-core includes org.clojure/clojure as dependencies.
  https://clojars.org/ring/ring-core

Which is better way?

Answer (score 3):

When you deploy a library to Clojars, you will be deploying a JAR file containing just the source of your own project, in general. The JAR file will not contain *any* of the dependencies in your project. Those will be specified in a `pom.xml` file that is also deployed to Clojars. That `pom.xml` file is auto-generated by Leiningen when it builds and deploys your JAR file to Clojars.

When other projects depend on your library, they will get the code from the JAR file and the accompanying `pom.xml` will tell them what other libraries are needed to use your code. Leiningen automatically downloads those other libraries, once it has downloaded your library from Clojars.

Since all such projects are going to require Clojure itself to run them, they will already have a dependency on Clojure -- so it won't matter whether your project indicates a dependency on Clojure or not.

Comment: This ignores the possibility of a Java program that depends on a Clojure library. All Clojure projects should have an explicit dependency on `org.clojure/clojure`, because they in fact depend on it to function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I understood your answer as a difference is none because everyone who wants to run my library has org.clojure/clojure itself.

From your answer, It seems better to remove org.clojure/clojure in dependencies.
Because people who use different clojure version can use my library if I removed org.clojure/clojure in :dependencies.
(Probably, I have to specify clojure version in :dependencies)

Is it right?

Comment: thank you, amalloy. I understood your comments.